# Show 'column bar' (name,date...) in windows explorer

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

how can I enable the 'column bar' in the windows explorer (ec7)? I.e. the bar where the files can be sorted by name/size/type and column width can be adjusted.

On our CE6 device, it is displayed. On our EC7 device, not.

Already compared the registry settings of those two devices. Also, MS documentation doesn't give any hint.

Thanks for any input!

Regards, Timm.

Answer (score 0):

In explorer : View > Details

In Registry :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Explorer]
"ListStyle"="1" ; "0" Large Icons, "1" Detail, "2" Small Icons, "3" Liste Icons
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But switching to detail view doesn't make the column bar appear (as it usually does, e.g. with our CE6 devices).

Maybe some issue with screen size (QVGA) or the EC7-BSP (AM3517)?